# Error method has a cyclomatic complexity and nested if error

Tags: apex, trigger, visualforce-component, pmd

Please find the below trigger handler which is not passing PMD rules.

Error 1."Deeply nested if..then statements are hard to read" for following class:

```
Public Class LeadTriggerHandler {

    //Set previous owner Id and bypass the queue owners.
    public static void updateOwnersEmail(list<Lead> newLeadList,Map<Id,Lead> oldLeadMap){

        if(!oldLeadMap.isempty() && oldLeadMap!=null){
            for(Lead lRecord :newleadList) {
                Lead oldLeadRecord= oldLeadMap.get(lRecord.Id);
                if(oldLeadRecord.OwnerId!=null && lRecord.OwnerId!=null){
                    if(oldLeadRecord.OwnerId != lRecord.OwnerId && ((String) oldLeadRecord.OwnerId).startsWith( '005' ) ){
                        lRecord.Previous_Owner_ID__c= oldLeadRecord.OwnerId;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error 2. Modified same class as below got error agian " method 'updateOwnersEmail(List,Map)' has a cyclomatic complexity of 10."

```
Public Class LeadTriggerHandler {    
 //Set previous owner Id and bypass the queue owners.
 public static void updateOwnersEmail(list<Lead> newLeadList,Map<Id,Lead> oldLeadMap){        
   if(!oldLeadMap.isempty() && oldLeadMap!=null){
    list<Lead> oldLeadOwnerIds=new list<Lead>(); 
    for(Lead lRecord :newleadList) {
        if(oldLeadMap.get(lRecord.Id).OwnerId !=null)  { 
            Lead oldLeadRecord= oldLeadMap.get(lRecord.Id);
            oldLeadOwnerIds.add(oldLeadRecord);    
        }           
    }    
    if(!oldLeadMap.isempty() && oldLeadMap!=null && !oldleadOwnerIds.isempty() && oldleadOwnerIds!=null){
         for(Lead lRecord :newleadList) {
             Lead oldLeadRecord= oldLeadMap.get(lRecord.Id);
            if(oldLeadRecord.OwnerId!=null && lRecord.OwnerId!=null){
               if(oldLeadRecord.OwnerId != lRecord.OwnerId && ((String) oldLeadRecord.OwnerId).startsWith( '005' ) ){
                  lRecord.Previous_Owner_ID__c= oldLeadRecord.OwnerId;                    }
          }
            if(oldLeadRecord.OwnerId != lRecord.OwnerId && ((String) oldLeadRecord.OwnerId).startsWith( '005' ) ){
                lRecord.Previous_Owner_ID__c= oldLeadRecord.OwnerId;
            }                  
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of those are code style issues, not functionality. At that level you should take it up with your lead, or whomever set up PMD on your system.

However, you have some irrelevant logic here that you can remove. So much of this code does nothing that I would strongly recommend you step back, think through the logic, and rewrite the entire method (which can be *very* simple), while removing almost all of your `null`/empty checks, which you don't need here.

```
if(!oldLeadMap.isempty() && oldLeadMap!=null){
```

If you're calling this and supplying `Trigger.oldMap` in an `update` event, this will never be `null`. Iterating over an empty collection doesn't crash; it's just a no-op. In any case, checking for `null` after you call a method on the object is worse than useless - you already got the `NullPointerException` at that point.

You also do not need to check if `OwnerId` is null:

```
    if(oldLeadMap.get(lRecord.Id).OwnerId !=null)  { 
    if(oldLeadRecord.OwnerId!=null && lRecord.OwnerId!=null){
```

And you have this code block pasted twice:

```
        if(oldLeadRecord.OwnerId != lRecord.OwnerId && ((String) oldLeadRecord.OwnerId).startsWith( '005' ) ){
            lRecord.Previous_Owner_ID__c= oldLeadRecord.OwnerId;
        }
```

Plus, you can remove this entire code block, since it doesn't do anything and you don't use the results:

```
for(Lead lRecord :newleadList) {
    if(oldLeadMap.get(lRecord.Id).OwnerId !=null)  { 
        Lead oldLeadRecord= oldLeadMap.get(lRecord.Id);
        oldLeadOwnerIds.add(oldLeadRecord);    
    }           
}
```